# Can not create new activity in imported android project from intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have imported the IntelliJ android project in Android studio in this case.The app works but I can't add new activity after importing it doesn't work..compilation error occurs .I have tried many times but couldn't. Please share me your points on this issue.
Thanks..

Comment: What error appears?

Comment: Please specify the error

Comment: pls specify which error are u getting,without any error how we are tell about this issue?

Comment: Error:(395) Attribute "theme" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(392) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(395) Attribute "theme" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(392) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: and cant, resolve R in all activities